# How to create a subroutine in MUMPS on Mac os X

Tags: macos, editor, subroutine, mumps

I'm starting a project where I need to have some reading knowledge of MUMPs, the Massachusetts General Hospital Utility Multi-Programming System.  I've managed to get it working on my OS X El Capitan computer.  I can do some of the simple things, but cannot seem to create a simple subroutine.  According to the specs that I can find, a subroutine is created by a label then followed by lines that start with a tab or blank and instructions, so that

```
HELLO
   WRITE "Hello, World!",!
   QUIT
```

would be a subroutine that I could invoke using

```
DO HELLO
```

When I try to enter it, it immediately executes the WRITE statement.

Also, many examples are of the form:

```
DEMO 
   Kill For i=1:1:10 SET Ary(i)=i*2
   DO Average Write !,"Average=",AVG
   KILL Ary,AVG,i
   QUIT
Average  SET Sum=0;
   ;  Do something here
   QUIT
```

When I start typing the DO Average  line, I get an error that Average isn't defined.

Any ideas on how one enters the subroutine?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. But having limited time, I don't want to ask after why it isn't working. I would suggest asking on comp.lang.mumps. There are tons of people there who can help you. --Sam (Programmed in M for 8 years now).

Comment: What version of M/Mumps are you using? (Or is it really Caché ObjectScript?)

Comment: I'm using Cache 2016.1, but I don't know if it's ObjectScript.  I'm using it from the terminal and have a VistA CACHE.DAT file.  I can't figure out how to get a listing of the executable functions in that file and can't figure out how to write one from the terminal and save it as a global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all between `Kill` and `For`, should be more then 1 space, and if it os only one space, then `For` became a variable and should be killed.
Then you are were wrong when recognized UNDEFINED error for command `DO Average`, you have another UNDEFINED error in the same line and it is `AVG` variable, which is really undefined in your code.
If you just in the begin of understanding MUMPS language, I would recommend to write every command on a separate line.

Comment: Thanks. This was a big help. Fixed that, then put code into a file and did: DO ^filename and it worked!  On a quick note, how do I close an issue once I'm happy with the answer and "reward" the person answering?